# homepage redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

A few questions about homepage redirects:

I want my homepage to always be http://www.mydomain.com/

I've had the following code in my htaccess for awhile in order to make sure that http://www.mydomain.com/index.html is redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/ (at least I think that's what it's for).

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Do I also need to add separate code such as that below to redirect http://mydomain.com/ to http://www.mydomain.com/? Or does the above code accomplish both? (Because both redirects seem to be already working, I'm just not sure why it's already redirecting for http://mydomain.com/)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond % ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also, is it necessary to set the preferred domain in google webmaster tools to www.mydomain.com if I am using these 301 redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current rule will not handle both e.g. `mydomain.com/about.html` would not redirect to `www.mydomain.com/about.html` (assuming about.html existed)
If you want to ensure that people only access your site through `www.mydomain.com` then add the following rule to your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if the domain is not www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#redirect to www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#leave this rule in place, but after the one above to handle the home page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

With this rule in place, you can only access your site through `www.mydomain.com`, so there is no need to set the preferred domain in google webmaster tools.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if I'm following you correctly, what you are saying is if I use the code you provided and take out the code that I had in there, it will take care of all of the necessary redirects including http://www.mydomain.com/index.html, http://mydomain.com/index.html & http://mydomain.com/, making them all go to http://www.mydomain.com/ ??

Comment: If you use the code above, which includes your rule for index.html, it should work as you requested